# Render HTML from JSON object returned from controller to jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In ASP.NET MVC 4 how can I render HTML on load. I am saving some html string encoded in this form in my sql server database as type nvarchar(max).

```
&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;&amp;lt;img id=&amp;quot;fbPic&amp;quot; src=&amp;quot;http://graph.facebook.com/567818188/picture&amp;quot; style=&amp;quot;display: inline; padding-right: 10px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Bernice Zerafa&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;&amp;lt;pre class=&amp;quot;word-wrap&amp;quot; style=&amp;quot;margin-left: 10%;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;hellooo&amp;lt;/pre&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;
```

**EDIT:**Please note that the above string is being html unencoded correctly therefore it actually shows like this:

```
<li><li><img id="fbPic" src="http://graph.facebook.com/567818188/picture" style="display: inline; padding-right: 10px;"><b>Bernice Zerafa</b></li><pre class="word-wrap" style="margin-left: 10%;">helloooo </pre></li>
```

Now on load of the page I will have a list of those html strings which are all list items with various childnodes to be appended to a unordered list tag. The list is returning ok. But it's only being displayed as is on the page i.e. the actual string is showing and the html is not being rendered.

This is my Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult LoadPosts(int groupId)
{
     var postedText = new List<string>();
     IEnumerable<Post> posts;

     using (CodeShareEntities conn = new CodeShareEntities())
     {
          posts = conn.Posts.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId); 
          foreach (var post in posts)
          {
               postedText.Add(post.PostData);
          }
     }

     return Json(new { PostedText = postedText });
}
```

This is my jQuery Ajax call on load of the page. `#posts` is an empty `<ul>` in my html

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST', 
     url: '/Groups/LoadPosts',
     data: { groupId: grpid },
     success: function (postData) {
          $.each(postData, function (index, postText) {
                 **postText = htmlUnencode(postText);**
                 $("#posts")[0].innerHTML = postText;

                //// what can I do here instead of innerHTML to be 
                //// able to view the html correctly ? 
                //// append() and insert() methods in JQuery have the same result
                //// I found something called @Html.Raw(Json.Encode()) maybe
                //// this is relevant here ? How can I use this correctly ?

          });

          $('#posts').css('background', 'white');
     },
     traditional: true
  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your html is double encoded. Try this

```
     $.each(postData, function (index, postText) {
             **postText = htmlUnencode(postText);**
             $("#posts").append($($("<div/>").html($("<div/>").html(test).text()).text()));
      });
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s7Lq/) sample.

Comment: That did the trick! I've been searching for ages! thought I had to render it in some other way! Thanks!!

Comment: hmm.. But see if there is a better way to do it. Also it seems like it is double encoded ex:- instead of `&amp;lt;` it should be `&lt;` i guess. YOu are welcome btw... :)

Comment: so what are you doing exactly in this code please? mmm I'll look into that too!

Comment: What this does is set the escaped data to a temp div's html and get .text() of it which will unescape the string but since this is double escaped had to do it once more... :)

Comment: @Bernice try this. In your server before sending back the string do this `htmlstring = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlstring)` and send back and in the ajax call just do it once. `$("#posts").append($("<div/>").html(test).text())`

Comment: oh I see! I found what I was doing! While testing I also did WebUtility.HtmlEncode in the controller so I was encoding it from the js side and there too! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

just by looking at your

```
&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;&amp;lt;img id=&amp;quot;fbPic&amp;quot; src=&amp;quot;http://graph.facebook.com/567818188/picture&amp;quot; style=&amp;quot;display: inline; padding-right: 10px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Bernice Zerafa&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;&amp;lt;pre class=&amp;quot;word-wrap&amp;quot; style=&amp;quot;margin-left: 10%;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;hellooo&amp;lt;/pre&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;
```

i doubt it going to render correctly it not seems like a valid html and you constantly appending so you might use something like

```
  $("#posts").append(postText);
```

Comment: no it is valid html and in fact the browser shows it as normal tags nested within an <li> . Tried append but still the text was being shown in the ul instead of the actual nodes

Comment: maybe you did not paste it correctly but it does not look valid to me http://jsfiddle.net/hdvLf/

Comment: you are right. I forgot to include the unencoding back to proper tags. Please see edit. I included how it's being shown exactly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdvLf/1/ so you want to see this bus instead you see just pure html string

Comment: exactly! That is the result I want but I'm seeing the actual html string